# minecraft yml file help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

When I use the console it says Syntax Error. I then tried to check if I have the group ownership; I'm shown as a normal user and this permissions.yml file changed nothing: no color, no prefix as Owner or anything!

Would any of you help me figure out what I did wrong?

```
groups:
    default: 
        default: true
        prefix: '&2Default&2'
        permissions:
        - modifyworld.'
        - -essentials.item
        - essentials.sethome
        - essentials.home
     Co-Owner:
        default: false
        prefix: '&5Co-Owner&5'
         permissions:
         - *

Users: 
    crazy_man_12
        group: Owner
        prefix '&4'        
        permissions:
        - *

Users:
    captain_colors50       
        group: Admin
        prefix: '&0'
        permissions: 
        - *
```

Comment: There is no question here. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: oh sorry is it right bcuz in my server its not showing up

Comment: Please don't just give us a chunk of code and expect us to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @crazy_man_12 Just [edit your post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/109547/edit) telling us what you expected, what happened, what that file is and we'll reopen the question :)

Comment: @crazy_man_12 Calm down, man.  Slow down, and explain what the problem is.  We can't understand you, and until we can, we can't help you.  Try to use proper punctuation, too, as that will help immensely.

Comment: Crazy man, please relax for a little while. Asking duplicate questions isn't going to get you an answer faster; taking the time to explain your problem in a few coherent sentences will. In particular I think it might be helpful to specify 1. where have you put the file? 2. I don't think Bukkit actually give you prefixes on chat out of the box; have you configured that somehow? 3. what commands do you expect to be able to run but can't?

Comment: Vanilla Minecraft does not have any kind of configuration file like the one in the question. Therefore, crazy_man_12's minecraft must be modded, making his question off-topic as modded minecraft tech support.

Comment: @pppery it's a bukkit file.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are running a CraftBukkit server. Each permission system for CraftBukkit is different, and has a slightly different way of structuring their config files, thus it is very difficult to give plugin-specific help for your problem. That being said, at first glance there are a multitude of potential problems in the given file:

**Problem #1** is 'modifyworld.' '. I have never seen nor heard of a permission that ends in '.' ', perhaps you meant to use 'modifyworld.*'?

**Problem #2** is not really a problem. You have your prefix variable for default as '&2Default&2'. The second '&2' on the end is not necessary to change the color of the text, only the code before the prefix text. Additionally you could add '&r' to reset the color before the actual player name is printed. This problem also occurs in '&5Co-Owner&5'.

**Problem #3** is in the naming if the Co-Owner group. The '-' in the name could possibly be disrupting your syntax, thus throwing the 'Syntax Error' on your console.

**Problem #4** is that you have two 'Users' tags. Instead of:

```
Users: 
    crazy_man_12
        group: Owner
        prefix '&4'        
        permissions:
        - *
Users:
    captain_colors50       
        group: Admin
        prefix: '&0'
        permissions: 
        - *
```

You could use something more like this:

```
Users: 
    crazy_man_12
        group: Owner
        prefix '&4'        
        permissions:
        - *
    captain_colors50       
        group: Admin
        prefix: '&0'
        permissions: 
        - *
```

**Problems #5 and #6** are also in this section. You need a colon after each of the player names for correct YAML structure. Also, you may need to use 'users' instead of 'Users' (lowercase vs. uppercase).

Lastly, **Problem #7** is that you have your two listed players in non-existent groups. You need to assign them to existing groups for their permissions to work.

**In conclusion**, your fixed file could look something like this:

```
groups:
    default: 
        default: true
        prefix: '&2Default&r'
        permissions:
        - modifyworld.*
        - -essentials.item
        - essentials.sethome
        - essentials.home
    CoOwner:
        default: false
        prefix: '&5Co-Owner&r'
        permissions:
        - *
users: 
    crazy_man_12:
        group: CoOwner
        prefix '&4'        
        permissions:
        - *
    captain_colors50:    
        group: CoOwner
        prefix: '&0'
        permissions: 
        - *
```